# Building and Running my First App

Tags: java

I am attempting to run my first app on my Droid Razor and this is the error I'm getting. The following is the code

```
[2013-07-06 15:52:34 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2013-07-06 15:52:34 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-07-06 15:52:34 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-07-06 15:52:34 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity   activity launch
[2013-07-06 15:52:34 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'NexusS'
[2013-07-06 15:52:34 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'NexusS'
[2013-07-06 15:52:41 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-07-06 15:52:41 - Emulator] 
[2013-07-06 15:52:41 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-07-06 15:52:41 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: `[2013-07-06 15:52:41 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8`

Answer (score 0):

How much memory are you allocating for the AVD? Sometimes there are issues when you use up to 1 GB. Try reducing the memory to 512 MB or lower, and see if that helps. From Google: "On Windows, emulating RAM greater than 768M may fail... Try progressively smaller values of RAM if the emulator fails to launch."